# Why is googlesheet reflecting time duration inaccurately (posted via python Sheety API)

Tags: python, datetime, google-sheets

[image: the result in sheet is shown in image]

The output is showing foreign formatting that I did not code.   How can I fix this so that is maintains duration as passed through the JSON?

```
exercise_endpoint = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v..
workout = input("What workouts did you do:")

query = {"query":workout}
header = {"x-app-id":APP_ID,
          "x-app-key":API_KEY}

exercise_response = requests.post(url=exercise_endpoint, json=query, headers=header)
date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

sheet_post_endpoint = 'https://api.sheety.co/..
sheety_header = {"Authorization": "Bearer ..."}
response_as_dict = exercise_response.json()
workouts = response_as_dict['exercises']
for workout in workouts:
    # id = workout['tag_id']
    exercise = workout["name"].title()
    duration = workout["duration_min"]
    calories = workout["nf_calories"]

routine = {"workout":
                   {
                    # "id": id,
                    "date": date,
                    "time": time,
                    "exercise": exercise,
                    "duration": duration,
                    "calories": calories}
               }
print(routine)
sheet_post_response = requests.post(url=f"{sheet_post_endpoint}", json=routine, headers=sheety_header)
print(sheet_post_response.text)

get_response_url = "https://api.sheety.co/..../workoutsTracking/workouts"
print(requests.get(get_response_url).json())`
```

I can't figure out why in the Googles Sheets it is updating as shown in the photo attached.
The output is showing foreign formatting that I did not code. How can I fix this so that is maintains duration as passed through the dictionary?

```
 sheet_post_response = requests.post(url=f"{sheet_post_endpoint}",json=routine, headers=sheety_header)
    print(sheet_post_response.text)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. In order to correctly understand them, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? By the way, your showing image is the sample output you expect? And also, what is `python Sheety API`?

Comment: Thanks for responding,  the code is what created the last row on the photo attached, everything is a appearing well in it however the line ` "duration": 15,` should appear as 15 under the **duration** row, it coming out as 01 mins. Sheety links with google sheets via api calls, i did mine in pyhton

Comment: Please share an example sheet. (See [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed.) My guess would be that you are not conforming to how Google Sheet treats and displays time related data. But I can't help you without knowing the actual data (type/format) you are working with. I can only see the display in your image. And I don't know exactly what your program did with json input.

Comment: this is the page tied to sheety.co [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165fXVW0uc3eH6QMgwUMvheQTRW0-YIgDTWRm1z5-PLM/edit?usp=sharing] and manipulated with code as shown above, the details are formatted well until the duration column

Comment: Hi there @user15316630! I am replicating this scenario in order to understand why the format changes. Could you please share the minimal Python script that replicates this behaviour on the Sheets API?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeronthank you, and sorry for not responding early, i was offline. i have added the code on the question

Comment: @user15316630 Thank you for the update. I can't reproduce your scenario because I don't have access to the Nutritionix API. Nevertheless I see that you aren't using the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api), but are using the Sheety API instead. To prevent a faulty third-party API, could you please test the Sheets API? I recommend you using the [`spreadsheets.values.append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) method.

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron
     Thank you, Thank you very much for showing interest in helping me out, I can share my API with you, is it possible to email me on theperson0004@gmail.com. Your about is leaving m in stitches by the way